# Extracting weights from an LSTM neural network using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have trained a recurrent neural network (LSTM) in keras but now I am struggling to put all the pieces together. Specifically, I cannot understand how to recompose the matrices of weights.

I have one input, one hidden and one output layer, as follows:

```python
# create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
```

when I call `model.get_weights()` I only get the bias units for the hidden and output layers but the ones for the input layers appear missing. Namely, I have a 15x400 matrix, then a 400x101 and a 101X5.

Is there something that I am missing out here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: what are the values of data_dim and timesteps?

Comment: data_dim = 15
timesteps = 20
1000 training examples
5 classes

Comment: UP! Anyone helping with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sequential is a model in Keras, not an input layer.
An input layer in a neural network is simply passing the inputs to the hidden layer and it does not need a bias neuron . 
In your case, the model.get_weights() returns these arrays
(15, 400) 
(100, 400) 
(400,)
(100, 5)
(5,)
Out of which
 (400,) is the bias array for the LSTM layer

(5,) is the bias array  for the Dense layer

Comment: Thanks user239457 for your answer.

Why do I have a (15,400) matrix and not a (15,100) matrix?